# Make notifications/messages fill the screen

Tags: notifications, sms

Is there a way to have it so notifications/messages fill the screen, so I can't help but notice them when I pick my phone up?

Using an LG-Ally

Comment: If you're not in the habit of looking at the notification bar, are notifications really that important to you? :P

Comment: well I'm not used to looking at that from other phones

Comment: Android's notification bar are specifically designed to be non-obstrusive since it assumes that the current task is most important.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SMS Popup](http://www.appbrain.com/app/sms-popup/net.everythingandroid.smspopup) will create a modal dialog box on your screen when you receive a text message.  You can make it turn the screen on too if the phone's screen is off.

[Handcent](http://www.appbrain.com/app/handcent-sms/com.handcent.nextsms) (full SMS replacement app) also has a similar feature built into it.

Comment: Is there any way to get a similar feature for all notifications?

Comment: @babonk so you want anything that shows up in the notification bar to be fully visible?  hmm...  I don't know of any off the top of my head

Comment: I see lots of apps that let you add things to the existing notification bar, but nothing that changes the notification bar to take up some/all of the screen.

Comment: +1 for SMS Popup, first app I recommend to new Android users. Something similar really should have been built into the OS by now.

Answer (score 0):

If you click on the text message icon and go to your text message inbox, hit the settings button on youur phone and go to "settings."  Scroll down and you can select the box enabling the phone to provide a preview of the message text.