# Show messages on lock screen

Tags: lock-screens, samsung-galaxy-s-4

I'm looking for some sort of way that will show part/all of my text messages, emails, tweets on the screen when the phone is locked.

I just gave up my iPhone and this is something I'm really missing.

To me it is annoying to have to click on a message just to see if the person responded "ok" or something that could easily be displayed on the screen.

Here is a screen shot of the messaging.  I want to be able to read the text.

[image]

Comment: Best not to put multiple questions in a single question post. Also, questions that ask how to solve a problem will do better (and are much preferred) rather than questions asking to find an app that does some specific function.

Comment: @AlEverett Updated.  Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: Doesn't the S4 come with a whole bunch of widgets? Have you tried any of the built-in lock-screen widgets? (Sorry, I don't have an S4 so I don't know specifically what's available.) Have you tried looking on the Play Store for lock-screen widgets? There must be something there for messages.

Comment: Don't know about emails and tweets, but for text messages see this previous question http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4427/make-notifications-messages-fill-the-screen/4429#4429 which includes the SMS Popup app in the answer, which is what I use for this.

Comment: This may be helpful: http://www.androidcentral.com/how-get-lock-screen-widgets-samsung-galaxy-s4

Answer (score 7):

The S4 does have this option. Open the SMS app (Messaging) and go to *Settings* (using the drawer button on the bottom left of your phone). Within *Settings,* scroll down to notification settings and check the "notifications" box and the "preview message" box.

Note that to see the notification option in *Settings* you must access settings from the main screen of the Messaging app, not from within a conversation within Messaging. This is one of those apps that has different menus for "settings" depending on which screen you're currently viewing.

Answer (score 4):

If you were to download and use an alternate lockscreen like [WidgetLocker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.widgetlocker&hl=en), this would be possible. It would enable you to place a widget on your lockscreen that shows you unread messages, though you might have to get that widget separately if you're not using a third party SMS app already. If you're just looking for a count of unread messages, you could use something like [Ultimate Custom Clock Widget](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=in.vineetsirohi.customwidget&feature=search_result) too.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [SMSPopup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.everythingandroid.smspopup) which will allow it to show up on top of any application, including your lockscreen (it can even turn your phone on for a few seconds so you can see the pop up).

[Handcent](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.handcent.nextsms) also has a SMSPopup like ability. And [GoSMS](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jb.gosms) too.

Comment: gosms is my personal fav :)

Comment: Popover lockscreen for SMS is exactly why I use and love Handcent.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need any third party app for this. To preview text messages in the lock screen go to setting in the messages app. Check "preview messages". Now the actual text of the message will show on your lock screen.

Comment: This is likely an option specific to your phone's version of the Messages app. Mine doesn't have this ability natively, at least. Is your phone the same as the Questioners, a Galaxy S4?

Comment: This does seem to be applicable to the S4, at least according to [one S4 owner](http://forums.androidcentral.com/samsung-galaxy-s4/280261-text-message-preview-how-do-i-enable.html).

Answer (score 2):

[NiLS Notifications Lock Screen](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.roymam.android.notificationswidget) will display all notifications on the lock screen. In the case of an SMS message, it displays the content of the SMS message in the lock screen notification.

Answer (score 1):

I use [Handcent SMS](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.handcent.nextsms&hl=en) that allows me to view my messages when the phone is locked.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done via [Widget Locker App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.widgetlocker&hl=en). There are many customizations on lock screen using widgetlocker app.

If you need only SMS items to displayed there are several [Apps](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.everythingandroid.smspopup&hl=en) in market.

Alternatively, there is a option in settings to preview the whole sms in the notification bar

Answer (score 0):

[If you're coming to Google's platform from the iPhone, one of the most jarring changes is that receiving text messages doesn't turn your display on so you can see what's being said.](http://lifehacker.com/sms-wakeup-shows-your-texts-on-screen-when-you-receive-1277264011)

SMS WakeUp ([Free](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dberm22.SMSWakeUp)/[Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dberm22.SMSWakeUpPro)) fixes this problem.

> The app has a very simple purpose: when you receive a text message, the display will turn on for a moment, showing a pop-up that allows you to jump directly to the message itself. Alternatively, with the pro version ($0.99), you can disable the pop-up so you'll only see your lockscreen, where you'll be able to watch the regular Android notification as it scrolls past in the shade, completely hands-free.

Answer (score -2):

Enter the Messaging app and open the settings menu. You'll find an option that says Preview Message under the Notification settings. Checking this will allow you to see what the test says on the lock screen and in the notification bar.

Comment: This is basically the same answer as this one: http://android.stackexchange.com/a/45587/11190